# How to get Values of array from local storage and display it

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am trying to display an array from local storage but after refreshing the page when I hit the save button again the previous entries in local storage are replaced by the new ones and are not working correctly.

Js file:

```
let count = 0;
let countStr = []

let saveEl = document.getElementById("save-el")
let countEl = document.getElementById("count-el")
let resetBtn = document.getElementById("reset-btn")
let saveBtn = document.getElementById("save-btn")
let incrementBtn = document.getElementById("increment-btn")
const entriesFromLocalStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("entries"))


saveEl.innerHTML = entriesFromLocalStorage


incrementBtn.addEventListener("click" , function(){
    count = count + 1 ;
    countEl.innerHTML = count;
})


saveBtn.addEventListener("click" , function(){
    countStr.push(count)
    saveEl.innerHTML = countStr
    localStorage.setItem("entries", JSON.stringify(countStr))
     count = 0;
    countEl.innerHTML = 0;


})


resetBtn.addEventListener("click" , function(){
    saveEl.innerHTML = "";
    localStorage.clear()
})
```

HTML file:

```
<h1>People entered:</h1>
    <h2 id="count-el">0</h2>
    <button id="increment-btn">INCREMENT</button>
    <button id="save-btn">SAVE</button>
    <div class="entries">
        <p class="prev-ent">Previous entries:</p>
        <p id="save-el"></p>
    </div>
    <button id="reset-btn">Reset entries</button>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
```

Comment: `saveEl.innerHTML = entriesFromLocalStorage.join(', ');`

Comment: @MERN but the problem remains the same. when I refresh the page and the increment the count and hit save button the old entries are replaced by new ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let count = 0;
let countStr = []

let saveEl = document.getElementById("save-el")
let countEl = document.getElementById("count-el")
let resetBtn = document.getElementById("reset-btn")
let saveBtn = document.getElementById("save-btn")
let incrementBtn = document.getElementById("increment-btn")
const entriesFromLocalStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("entries") || '[]')

// This is important
countStr = entriesFromLocalStorage;

saveEl.innerHTML = entriesFromLocalStorage


incrementBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    count = count + 1;
    countEl.innerHTML = count;
})


saveBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    countStr.push(count)
    saveEl.innerHTML = countStr
    localStorage.setItem("entries", JSON.stringify(countStr))
    count = 0;
    countEl.innerHTML = 0;


})


resetBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    saveEl.innerHTML = "";
    localStorage.clear()
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can keep track of current and previous values in an object and store that object in local storage when you click save and retrieve same object when page loads.

Link to [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-sun-zpdqi?file=/src/index.js)

```js
let count = 0;
let countStr = [];

let saveEl = document.getElementById("save-el");
let countEl = document.getElementById("count-el");
let resetBtn = document.getElementById("reset-btn");
let saveBtn = document.getElementById("save-btn");
let incrementBtn = document.getElementById("increment-btn");
const entriesFromLocalStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("entries")) || {
  current: 0,
  previous: []
};

console.log(entriesFromLocalStorage);

saveEl.innerHTML = entriesFromLocalStorage.previous.toString() || 0;

incrementBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  count = count + 1;
  countEl.innerHTML = count;
});

saveBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log(entriesFromLocalStorage, "At Save");

  countStr.push(count);
  saveEl.innerHTML = countStr;
  entriesFromLocalStorage.current = count;
  entriesFromLocalStorage.previous.push(count);
  localStorage.setItem("entries", JSON.stringify(entriesFromLocalStorage));
  count = 0;
  countEl.innerHTML = 0;
});

resetBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  saveEl.innerHTML = "";
  localStorage.clear();
});
```

```html
<h1>People entered:</h1>
<h2 id="count-el">0</h2>
<button id="increment-btn">INCREMENT</button>
<button id="save-btn">SAVE</button>
<div class="entries">
  <p class="prev-ent">Previous entries:</p>
  <p id="save-el"></p>
</div>
<button id="reset-btn">Reset entries</button>
```

Link to [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-sun-zpdqi?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: @coder please upvote and accept my answer if it solves your problem. Thank you